# How to access extra fields from login page of spring security?

Tags: spring-security

In login page of spring security , I have company name , user name and password .
When i click on login button it redirects to index.jsp. I wnat to access the company name in index.jsp.
I am getting user name and password using

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
```

and

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getCredentials();
```

But I wnat to retrive company name. How to do that?

Comment: Instead of redirect, if you do forward after successful authentication then all request parameters will be available in index.jsp.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say that you been login and you need to get company name that you been retrieve from database. First you will need to object that implement `UserDetails` that will save in `UserDetailsService` and add any variable that you need (company, etc).

```
public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails{      
    private String password;
    private String username;
    private String companyName;
}
```

than at typecast with your custom Userdetails implementation.

```
CustomUserDetails customDetails (CustomUserDetails)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getCredentials();
```

getCredentials will return `Object` of what you saved to the credential. Whatever it type you can always return it to the class you been save.